# Why does boost string give an error with clang and c++17?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, clang++

How do I make c++17 work with `boost/algorithm/string.hpp` and clang?

This program `test.cc`:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

when compiled with `clang++ -std=c++17 test.cc`, gives this error:

> In file included from test.cc:1:
>   In file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/algorithm/string.hpp:23: In file included
>   from /usr/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:16: In file
>   included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:27: In file
>   included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/find_iterator.hpp:24: In
>   file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_iterator.hpp:18:
>   In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/function.hpp:30: In
>   file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:17: In file
>   included from /usr/local/include/boost/function/function_base.hpp:21:
>   In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_index.hpp:29: In
>   file included from
>   /usr/local/include/boost/type_index/stl_type_index.hpp:43: In file
>   included from /usr/local/include/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp:110:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/optional:184:1:
>   error: unknown type name
>         '_LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_THROW_BAD_OPTIONAL_ACCESS'
>   _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_THROW_BAD_OPTIONAL_ACCESS

etc.

I am running on Mac, with the latest `clang++` from `xcode-select --install`, and the latest boost version from homebrew.

My boost version is 1.67, and `clang++` version is:

> Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)

If I change to `-std=c++14`, or if I take out `algorithm/string.hpp` and put in something else, like `boost/lambda/lambda.hpp` all is fine. `c++1z` gives the same error.

Comment: If you have a source file which is just `#include <optional>` with an empty main, does it compile?

Comment: I believe that Apple LLVM 9.1.0 simply doesn't properly support C++17, so you may just have to wait for them to do so, or else build a more recent clang yourself (unsure how to do this on apple computers)

Comment: @Justin Indeed, `<optional>` also yields errors.

Comment: Apple's Xcode clang++ C++17 support is incomplete.  Stick with C++14, or maybe install `brew install llvm` to use a more current clang that has better C++17 support.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks... I think I'll have to stick with c++14. As much as I want to play with the latest and greatest, others also need to run my code, and probably won't appreciate needing to install a new compiler.